# How to downgrade a certain ubuntu 10.04 package (php) back to karmic?

Tags: ubuntu, php, downgrade

I've updated from 9.10 to 10.04, but unfortunately the PHP provided with 10.04 is not yet supported by zend optimizer.

As far as I understand, I need to somehow replace the PHP 5.3 package provided under 10.04 with an older PHP 5.2 package provided under 9.10. However I'm not sure whether this is the right way to downgrade PHP and if yes, I don't know how to replace the 10.04 package with 9.10 package.

Could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thread will tell you exactly how to downgrade PHP from 5.3 to 5.2 in Ubuntu 10.04:

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1447401.html

**Update:** the [OP commented](https://serverfault.com/questions/138605/how-to-downgrade-a-certain-ubuntu-10-04-package-php-back-to-karmic/139114#comment117958_138618) below that the following script found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1459163) solved his issue.

```
#!/bin/bash
# by Ruben Barkow (rubo77) http://www.entikey.z11.de/

# Originally Posted by Bachstelze http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9080474#post9080474
# OK, here's how to do the Apt magic to get PHP packages from the karmic repositories:

echo "Am I root?  "
if [ "$(whoami &2>/dev/null)" != "root" ] && [ "$(id -un &2>/dev/null)" != "root" ] ; then
  echo "  NO!

Error: You must be root to run this script.
Enter
sudo su
"
  exit 1
fi
echo "  OK";


#install aptitude before, if you don`t have it:
apt-get install aptitude
# or if you prefer apt-get use:
# alias aptitude='apt-get'

# finish all apt-problems:
aptitude update
aptitude -f install
#apt-get -f install

# remove all your existing PHP packages. You can list them with dpkg -l| grep php
PHPLIST=$(for i in $(dpkg -l | grep php|awk '{ print $2 }' ); do echo $i; done)
echo these pachets will be removed: $PHPLIST 
# you need not to purge, if you have upgraded from karmic:
aptitude remove $PHPLIST
# on a fresh install, you need purge:
# aptitude remove --purge $PHPLIST


#Create a file each in /etc/apt/preferences.d like this (call it for example /etc/apt/preferences.d/php5_2);
#
#Package: php5
#Pin: release a=karmic
#Pin-Priority: 991
#
#The big problem is that wildcards don't work, so you will need one such stanza for each PHP package you want to pull from karmic:

echo ''>/etc/apt/preferences.d/php5_2
for i in $PHPLIST ; do echo "Package: $i
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991
">>/etc/apt/preferences.d/php5_2; done

# duplicate your existing sources.list replacing lucid with karmic and save it in sources.list.d:
#sed s/lucid/karmic/g /etc/apt/sources.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/karmic.list

# better exactly only the needed sources, cause otherwise you can get a cachsize problem:
echo "# needed sources vor php5.2:
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates universe

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security multiverse
" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/karmic.list

aptitude update

apache2ctl restart

echo install new from karmic:
aptitude -t karmic install $PHPLIST

# at the end retry the modul libapache2-mod-php5 in case it didn't work the first time:
aptitude -t karmic install libapache2-mod-php5

apache2ctl restart
```

Comment: Thanks! I also found this thread where someone crated and posted a script which does the work
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1459163

Answer (score 1):

This post tell you how to install php from "karmic" repository:
http://mrkandy.wordpress.com/2010/04/16/install-php-5-2-x-in-ubuntu-10-04-lucid/

Steps:

```
php_installed=`dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "`

# remove all php packge
sudo aptitude purge $php_installed

# use karmic for php pakage
# pin-params:  a (archive), c (components), v (version), o (origin) and l (label).
echo -e "Package: php5\nPin: release a=karmic\nPin-Priority: 991\n"  | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/php > /dev/null
apt-cache search php5-|grep php5-|awk '{print "Package:", $1,"\nPin: release a=karmic\nPin-Priority: 991\n"}'|sudo tee -a /etc/apt/preferences.d/php > /dev/null
apt-cache search -n libapache2-mod-php5 |awk '{print "Package:", $1,"\nPin: release a=karmic\nPin-Priority: 991\n"}'| sudo tee -a /etc/apt/preferences.d/php > /dev/null
echo -e "Package: php-pear\nPin: release a=karmic\nPin-Priority: 991\n"  | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/preferences.d/php > /dev/null

# add karmic to source list
egrep '(main restricted|universe|multiverse)' /etc/apt/sources.list|grep -v "#"| sed s/`lsb_release -s -c`/karmic/g | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/karmic.list > /dev/null

# update package database (use apt-get if aptitude crash)
sudo apt-get update

# install php
sudo apt-get install $php_installed
# or sudo aptitude install -t karmic php5-cli php5-cgi //for fcgi
# or  sudo apt-get install -t karmic  libapache2-mod-php5 //for apache module

sudo aptitude hold `dpkg -l | grep php5| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "`
#done
```